# How do I remove selective tables from a MySQL dump

Tags: mysql

How do I remove selective tables from a MySQL dump. I would like to remove the following tables from my dump file. How should I do this.

```
"DATABASECHANGELOG", "DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could take a mysqldump using the following command to ignore the specific tables on making dump , so you could step away from risks of  removing the tables after taking the dump

```
mysqldump -u username -p database_name --ignore-table=database_name.table1 --ignore-table=database_name.table2 > test.sql
```

Comment: Will I be able to provide table names in a comma separated format instead of separate arguments

Comment: Is'nt possible to give it in comma , we are supposed to use with arguments alone :)